# Expression Call for Starts With gives AmbiguousMatch Exeption

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
        case "StartsWith":
                return Expression.AndAlso(
                        Expression.Not(Expression.Call(typeof(string), (typeof(string).GetMethod("IsNullOrEmpty")).Name, null, member)),
                        Expression.Call(Expression.Call(member, "ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes), startsWithMethod, constExpression));
```

However it keeps throwing an exception "AmbiguousMatch found". What could be causing this error? I am debugging through the application and do not have any idea of using expression trees.

startsWith => `private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });`

Comment: What line throws the exception? I would suggest breaking up the `return` into multiple lines with variable assignments to see exactly where the exception is thrown. I assume it isn't in the `startsWithMethod` line?

Comment: What are the types/values of `member` and `constExpression`? I can't replicate an exception when I try each piece of the code using LINQPad and .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: Apologies. I should have posted the complete code. It wasnt actually coming from the line posted. `private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");` this was causing an error. just adding the Type to it fixed it. Thanks